# In a React application, applying the same font to all options in a <select> element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am a React noob. I am trying to apply the same font on a select element but it is only applied to the option displayed on the screen. I am getting it from Google Fonts as below. Here it is [this when I try to spread the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WJDM.png) [this is the normal look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbQbp.png)

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Monoton&family=Quicksand:wght@500;700&display=swap');
```

I tried to apply an inline style for each option but it didn't work. am i missing anything?

Comment: did you apply this fonts in the select dropdown class in css?
for example **``<select className="custom-select">``**
for the css **`` .custom-select {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
``**
Like this ?

Comment: You have to create the custom select option dropdown to achieve what you want. Default native html options you can't customize it. for more info read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option